# Call REST service over https using Apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, rest, https, apache-camel, ssl-certificate

I am using Apache Camel Spring DSL to call a REST service over HTTPS. The application is a Spring Boot application and the dependency camel-http is added in pom.xml. I have the certificate file Test.p12 and the password of the certificate. To add the certificate while calling the HTTPS URL, I am following the instructions given in

```
https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/http-component.html
```

and trying to add the following bean definition:

```
<camel:sslContextParameters
      id="sslContextParameters">
    <camel:keyManagers
        keyPassword="keyPassword">
      <camel:keyStore
          resource="/users/home/server/keystore.jks"
          password="keystorePassword"/>
    </camel:keyManagers>
  </camel:sslContextParameters>
```

but not able to create a bean. Can anyone please guide me how to call a REST service using HTTPS in Camel and how to add the certificate while calling?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: sslContextParameters is not getting recognized in XML

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Spring-Boot configuration of SSLContextParameters in the YAML (or property) file of the application.

You can find it at the [bottom of this page](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-configuration-utilities.html).

Comment: This did not work and I am getting the same exceltion: PKIX path validation failed